# elasticsearch 6.2 How to specify child and parent fields within one mapping(_doc)

Tags: elasticsearch-6

Since 6.2 no longer support multiple mapping type. I have to migrate existing multi type index into _doc type single mapping. However I am not sure how to map current child properties in this single mapping.

```
"mappings": {
         "_doc": {
            "properties": {
               "join_field": {
                  "type": "join",
                  "relations": {
                     "question": "answer"
                  }
               },
               "text": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

Now I wish to have more fields in answer type as well as in question type.But I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: You should just add all the fields into single mapping then while indexing you will specify what part of the relationship each document falls into (question or answer, if answer an optional parent doc id). See here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

Comment: how should I specify if a field is a question or answer. Currently what I am doing is adding all fields to a single mapping and for each doc(question or answer) I am adding data to the fields which are relevant. But this would lead to sparse documents as many fields are for answer which do not exist for question and vice versa.

Comment: Just like the doc says, set join type field as question or answer. When you set it to answer you can specify parent I'd in it too